# MouseHover on image jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

excuse the bad English
I'm using a translator
and ty for the help :)

I have a problem ,
the script is fine for what I want
the problem that as soon as the mouse leaves the image2-3-4
remains the image left(2-3-4)
instead of being the initial

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var changetimer;

    function change (id) {
        clearInterval (changetimer);
        function swap() {
            if ( id.src.match ( " images/img1.jpg ")) { = id.src id.src.replace ( " images/img1.jpg ", " images/img2.jpg ") return false; }
            if ( id.src.match ( " images/img2.jpg ")) { = id.src id.src.replace ( " images/img2.jpg ", " images/img3.jpg ") return false; }
            if ( id.src.match ( " images/img3.jpg ")) { = id.src id.src.replace ( " images/img3.jpg ", " images/img4.jpg ") return false; }
            if ( id.src.match ( " images/img4.jpg ")) { = id.src id.src.replace ( " images/img4.jpg ", " images/img1.jpg ") return false; }

        }
        changetimer = setInterval ( Swap , 1500 ) ;
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length ; i + +) {
            images[i]. onmouseover = function (evt) { change (this) ;}
            images[i]. onmouseout = function (evt) { clearInterval (changetimer); }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to try and explain in more detail what you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: If I understand what you're doing correctly, the problem is that your `onmouseout` event isn't changing the image back.  The image is changed by `onmouseover` and then never told to return to its original state.

Comment: @IanMcLaird : exactly :)

Comment: @IanMcLaird I put the string, but does not work. I uploaded a video
to better understand : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xdClVDQIPM&feature=youtu.be

As soon as the mouse leaves
remains the last image

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to use so many if statements, you could have just written something like this:

```
var array = [];
var images = document.getElementsByTagName ( ' img ');

for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
     array[i] = i;
     images[i].onmouseover = function () { 
        var timer = setInterval(function(){
           array[i]+= 1;
           this.src="images/img"+array[i]+".jpg";
        },1500);
        this.onmouseout = function () { clearInterval (timer); this.onmouseout=null;}
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is change this line:

```
images[i]. onmouseout = function (evt) { clearInterval (changetimer); }
```

So that it undoes whatever the `change` function does.  So something like this.

images[i]. onmouseout = function (evt) { clearInterval (changetimer); changeBack(this); }

Where `changeBack` is a function that does the opposite of whatever the `change` function does.